# Разобрать слово по составу 4

Tags: морфемный-разбор

Подскажите пожалуйста как разобрать по составу слово **посветлев**

Comment: Очередное домашнее задание от этого пользователя.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Посветлев*** -- деепричастие, образовано с помощью **формообразующего** суффикса ***в*** от глагола ***по-свет-л-е-ть,*** в котором ***по*** -- приставка, ***свет*** --  корень, ***л*** -- суффикс, ***е*** -- суффикс (см. словообразование этого глагола: **свет** -> свет-**л**(ый) -> светл-**е**-ть -> **по**-светлеть).

Итого:

*ПО+СВЕТ+Л+Е+В;* основа -- *ПОСВЕТЛЕ,*  окончания нет.